# Letter puzzle not working using cwpuzzle and beamer package

Tags: beamer, cwpuzzle

It is needed to implement a Letter puzzle using cwpuzzle and beamer package. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[unboxed]{cwpuzzle} %Para hacer pupiletras musicales
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\centering

\begin{Puzzle}{16}{12}
    |*    |*    |[1]R  |A  |[2]S  |T     |E     |R     |I     |Z     |A    |D    |O    |[3]S |*  |*    |.
    |*    |*    |*     |*  |V     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |T    |*  |[4]T |.
    |*    |[5]L |*     |*  |G     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |Y    |*  |E    |.
    |[6]B |A    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |X    |.
    |E    |T    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    |A    |E    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[7]M |I    |K    |T    |E  |X    |.
    |M    |X    |*     |*  |*     |[8]V  |E     |C     |T     |O     |R    |I    |A    |L    |*  |*    |.
    |E    |M    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[9]X  |E    |L    |A    |T    |E  |X    |.
    |R    |K    |*     |*  |[10]P |E     |R     |L     |*     |[11]L |A    |T    |E    |X    |*  |*    |.
    |*    |R    |[12]T |*  |[13]M |U     |S     |I     |X     |T     |E    |X    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    |*    |C    |T     |*  |*     |[14]B |M     |P     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    |*    |*    |F     |*  |[15]T |I     |K     |Z     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
\end{Puzzle}
    
\begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Horizontal}}
    \Clue{1}{RASTERIZADOS}{Any mathematical process}
    \Clue{7}{MIKTEX}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
    \Clue{8}{VECTORIAL}{A network of lines used for locating points}
    \Clue{9}{XELATEX}{Any symbol that could represent a number}
    \Clue{10}{PERL}{Graph that displays data using line segments}
    \Clue{11}{LATEX}{A model or drawing based on a ratio}
    \Clue{13}{MUSIXTEX}{Any mathematical process}
    \Clue{14}{BMP}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
    \Clue{15}{TIKZ}{A network of lines used for locating points}
\end{PuzzleClues}
    
\begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Vertical}}
    \Clue{2}{STY}{the positions of a single digit in the whole number}
    \Clue{3}{TEX}{A graph that uses bars to display data}
    \Clue{4}{LATEXMKRC}{The use of rounding to determine a reasonable answer}
    \Clue{5}{SVG}{The number found most often}
    \Clue{6}{BEAMER}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
    \Clue{12}{TTF}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
\end{PuzzleClues}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `fragile` frame:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[unboxed]{cwpuzzle} %Para hacer pupiletras musicales
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{?`Qué es \underline{Musixtex}?}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
\PuzzleUnitlength=13pt
\begin{Puzzle}{16}{12}
    |*    |*    |[1]R  |A  |[2]S  |T     |E     |R     |I     |Z     |A    |D    |O    |[3]S |*  |*    |.
    |*    |*    |*     |*  |V     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |T    |*  |[4]T |.
    |*    |[5]L |*     |*  |G     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |Y    |*  |E    |.
    |[6]B |A    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |X    |.
    |E    |T    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    |A    |E    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[7]M |I    |K    |T    |E  |X    |.
    |M    |X    |*     |*  |*     |[8]V  |E     |C     |T     |O     |R    |I    |A    |L    |*  |*    |.
    |E    |M    |*     |*  |*     |*     |*     |*     |*     |[9]X  |E    |L    |A    |T    |E  |X    |.
    |R    |K    |*     |*  |[10]P |E     |R     |L     |*     |[11]L |A    |T    |E    |X    |*  |*    |.
    |*    |R    |[12]T |*  |[13]M |U     |S     |I     |X     |T     |E    |X    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    |*    |C    |T     |*  |*     |[14]B |M     |P     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
    |*    |*    |F     |*  |[15]T |I     |K     |Z     |*     |*     |*    |*    |*    |*    |*  |*    |.
\end{Puzzle}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\scriptsize
\begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Horizontal}}
    \Clue{1}{RASTERIZADOS}{Any mathematical process}
    \Clue{7}{MIKTEX}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
    \Clue{8}{VECTORIAL}{A network of lines used for locating points}
    \Clue{9}{XELATEX}{Any symbol that could represent a number}
    \Clue{10}{PERL}{Graph that displays data using line segments}
    \Clue{11}{LATEX}{A model or drawing based on a ratio}
    \Clue{13}{MUSIXTEX}{Any mathematical process}
    \Clue{14}{BMP}{The lowest value in a set of numbers through the highest value in the set}
    \Clue{15}{TIKZ}{A network of lines used for locating points}
\end{PuzzleClues}

\begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Vertical}}
    \Clue{2}{STY}{the positions of a single digit in the whole number}
    \Clue{3}{TEX}{A graph that uses bars to display data}
    \Clue{4}{LATEXMKRC}{The use of rounding to determine a reasonable answer}
    \Clue{5}{SVG}{The number found most often}
    \Clue{6}{BEAMER}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
    \Clue{12}{TTF}{The horizontal and vertical number lines used in a graph}
\end{PuzzleClues}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case we need to scale the Puzzle, which command should be used?

Comment: In case we need to change the default colors with other colors, which commands should be used? (lets say white and black with yellow and gray)

Comment: @ABV I already scaled the puzzle down because the default size did not fit onto a slide. See the code in my answer

Comment: @ABV If you have a new question on changing the colours you should ask a new question